# Suggestion: do not use "The" for ordering in drop-down list of SE sites

Tags: feature-request, sorting, communities-list

So in the top-left-hand corner of each website there's a button saying 'StackExchange' with a drop-down including 'More Stack Exchange Communities'.

It's a long list. The communities are ordered alphabetically by title.

I was looking for "The Workplace" so I looked under "W".

Turns out it's under "T" for "The".

I suggest that [the definite article ('*the*') be disregarded from site names for ordering purposes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order#The_and_other_common_words).

So "The Workplace" would appear under "W", and "The Great Outdoors" would appear under "G" (or "O"?).

Comment: Interesting read for you, in case you missed it: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/4274/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-name-change-from-professional-matters-to-the :)

Comment: Thanks @ShadowWizard, that's interesting, although I'm *not* suggesting that there's anything wrong with names that start with 'The'.

Comment: Cheers, and you can also see in the [Area 51 proposal revisions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/30887/revisions) that the name was suggested by the chief Area 51 Community Manager himself, Robert, not by the users proposing the site. (original name was "Around the Water Cooler")

Answer (score 3):

They added a search box exactly for such cases.

> [image]

Problem fixed. :)

Comment: Well, not really, because I wasn't searching, I was scrolling alphabetically. Expected it to be at the bottom ("W") so just dragged the scrollbar right down, and was surprised not to find it. It's not that I couldn't find it in the end - I did find it - but that normal practise for listing things by title is to disregard articles, as per the wikipedia link I included. It's not unusable as it is, it would just have better usability if it were changed.

Comment: @AE I see your point, but think of all the people who are used to "The" in the beginning and would look for it under "T". If your request will be done, they will start a bug report "sorting it broken". What will you tell them?

Comment: Easy fix - prepend each site name with "the" :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I'd suggest that standard English usage should over-rule past Stack Exchange usage. Otherwise if I were to ask Bill Gates to fix MS Windows and he were to reply "but it's always been broken, we can't change it now, it would confuse people!" then I wouldn't have a leg to stand on. ;)

Comment: @nicael The The Workplace? ;P

Comment: @AE also, looks like "The" is integral part of the site name. Proper fix is asking to change the name of the site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I agree that "The" is an integral part of the site name; I don't think it follows that the proper fix is to ask to change the site name. "The" is an integral part of "The Big Lebowski" too, but generally (in a list of titles) [one would list it under 'B' rather than ask the Coen brothers to change the name of the movie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210532/sort-query-results-alphabetically-but-exclude-the-in-sorting). There's nothing *wrong* with a title that starts with 'The', it just shouldn't (in this context) be sort-ordered under 'T'. IMO.

Comment: @Yannis No problem, let's prepend "the" one more time... oh, wait :D